# JS - Iterating objects in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I can't seem to figure out this problem. I need to iterate over some objects, as of right now, named column_1, column_2, column_3 and column_4.

How do i use the i variable, to get the correct object?
This is my code right now, which isn't working...

```
for (var i = 1; i < layouts.columns; i++) {
    console.log(layouts.column_[i]);
}
```

Comment: it'd be good to see more code, like how is that object you're trying to iterate over

Comment: You need to use square bracket notation like `layouts['column_' + i]` and the condition should probably be `i <= layouts.length`.

Comment: Provide more code. How is layouts structured?

Comment: Have a look here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you need to iterate over the properties of an object?

It's not like an array. You have to do something like

```
   let keys = Object.keys(layouts.columns);
   for(var i = 0; i < keys.length -1; i ++ ) {// do stuff};
```

or

```
   for (var key in layouts.columns) { 
      var column = layouts.columns[key];
   }
```

Or like others have mentioned, if all property names are column_x, you could loop through 4, and access like `layouts['column_'+i]`

Comment: Like @RobG wrote in comment, `layouts['column_ + i]` worked perfectly :)